# SOQL query onProcessInstanceStep

Tags: soql

I am trying to do query on ProcessInstanceStep object,but I keep on getting null values.

I am trying to query comments values for the steps which are Rejected.

I am getting desired ID value of ProcessInstance,but it is not returning any value on ProcessInstanceStep.

Code:

```
for(ProcessInstance  pr : [Select id,ProcessDefinitionId,TargetObjectId from ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId =:'a233B0000001iqu']){
    defID.add(pr.id);
    system.debug('setcheck'+defID);

    for(ProcessInstanceStep pri : [Select id,Comments,StepStatus,ProcessInstanceId from ProcessInstanceStep where ProcessInstanceId =:pr.id and StepStatus='Rejected']){
        priMap.put(dcr.id,pri.Comments);
        system.debug('testing1..'+pri.Comments);
    } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try the query on [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/)?

Comment: Hey Santanu,I have tried it on developer console and it is working.But I am using the above mentioned code in trigger.Trigger is on Custom Object.So,when Approval step is rejected,Status field on custom object gets updated to Rejected which fires trigger.

Comment: Yes,I understand that but since status on object get updated to rejected only when on rejecting the approval step,so I think ProcessInstanceStep record get created before after update trigger gets executed.Please correct me if I am wrong.


Actually i am trying fetch comment field value from ProcessInstanceStep and then I will be using that value in emailMessaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry for the misleading comment, I have removed it.

When you have the field update on Final Rejection Actions, you will have the `ProcessInstanceStep` record in the object trigger. When you have a field update on `Approval Steps Action` you will not get the rejection comments in the trigger as by the time control reaches the trigger the `ProcessInstanceStep` records are not created. So move your field update to Final Rejection Action, you should be getting the rejection comments in the trigger.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @devsfdc If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.